# PHPMailer class not found when including the class

Tags: php, phpmailer, mailer

I have installed PHPMailer from github as a download master.zip

When I use it below

```
<?php

require "PHPMailer.php"; //include phpmailer class

// Instantiate Class
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Set up SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
$mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
$mail->Encoding = '7bit';
```

I get the following

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-156:/opt/PHPMailer-master/src$ php test.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /opt/PHPMailer-master/src/test.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /opt/PHPMailer-master/src/test.php on line 6
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-156:/opt/PHPMailer-master/src$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Folder structure attached
[image]

Comment: is PHPMailer.php in the folder you're trying to access? Possibly attach a screenshot of your folder structure and where PHPMailer.php is.

Comment: attached -- question updated.

Comment: it doesn't the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I had totally misread the error message, See the answer you already got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHPMailer by default is in the PHPMailer\PHPMailer namespace, you can bring it into the global namespace by using the `use` keyword. For example in their [simple_contact_form](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/simple_contact_form.phps) example:

```
<?php
//Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

Comment: How to load and instantiate PHPMailer is covered in the readme file, both with and without composer.